# Return multiple relationship counts for one MATCH statement

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to do something like this:

`MATCH (p:person)-[a:UPVOTED]->(t:topic),(p:person)-[b:DOWNVOTED]->(t:topic),(p:person)-[c:FLAGGED]->(t:topic) WHERE ID(t)=4 RETURN COUNT(a),COUNT(b),COUNT(c)`

..but I get all 0 counts when I should get 2, 1, 1

Comment: Not really sure why this was downvoted...

Comment: Someone doesn't like me or neo4j?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A better solution is to use `size` which improve drastically the performance of the query :

```
MATCH (t:Topic)
WHERE id(t) = 4
RETURN size((t)<-[:DOWNVOTED]-(:Person)) as downvoted,
       size((t)<-[:UPVOTED]-(:Person)) as upvoted,
       size((t)<-[:FLAGGED]-(:Person)) as flagged
```

If you are sure that the other nodes on the relationships are always labelled with Person, you can remove them from the query and it will be a bit faster again

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with refactoring the query a bit (hopefully the meaning of it isn't lost):

```
MATCH
  (t:topic)
  (p:person)-[upvote:UPVOTED]-(t),
  (p:person)-[downvote:DOWNVOTED]->(t),
  (p:person)-[flag:FLAGGED]->(t)
WHERE ID(t)=4
RETURN COUNT(upvote), COUNT(downvote), COUNT(flag)
```

Since `t` is your primary variable (since you are filtering on it), I've matched once with the label and then used just the variable throughout the rest of the matches.  Seeing the query cleaned up like this, it seems to me that you're trying to count all upvotes/downvotes/flags for a topic, but you don't care who did those things.  Currently, since you're using the same variable `p` Cypher is going to try to match the same person for all three lines.  So you could have different variables:

```
 (p1:person)-[upvote:UPVOTED]-(t),
 (p2:person)-[downvote:DOWNVOTED]->(t),
 (p3:person)-[flag:FLAGGED]->(t)
```

Or better, since you're not referencing the people anywhere else, you can just leave the variables out:

```
(:person)-[upvote:UPVOTED]-(t),
(:person)-[downvote:DOWNVOTED]->(t),
(:person)-[flag:FLAGGED]->(t)
```

And stylistically, I would also suggest starting your matches with the item that you're filtering on:

```
(t)<-[upvote:UPVOTED]-(:person)    
(t)<-[downvote:DOWNVOTED]-(:person)    
(t)<-[flag:FLAGGED]-(:person)
```

The next problem comes in because by making these a `MATCH`, you're saying that there NEEDS to be a match.  Which means you'll never get cases with zeros.  So you'll want `OPTIONAL MATCH`:

```
MATCH (t:topic)
WHERE ID(t)=4
OPTIONAL MATCH (t)<-[upvote:UPVOTED]-(:person)    
OPTIONAL MATCH (t)<-[downvote:DOWNVOTED]-(:person)    
OPTIONAL MATCH (t)<-[flag:FLAGGED]-(:person)    
RETURN COUNT(upvote), COUNT(downvote), COUNT(flag)
```

Even then, though what you're saying is: "Find a topic and find all cases where there is 1 upvote, no downvote, no flag, 1 upvote, 1 downvote, no flag, etc... to all permutations).  That means you'll want to `COUNT` one at a time:

```
MATCH (t:topic)
WHERE ID(t)=4
OPTIONAL MATCH (t)<-[r:UPVOTED]-(:person)    
WITH t, COUNT(r) AS upvotes

OPTIONAL MATCH (t)<-[r:DOWNVOTED]-(:person)    
WITH t, upvotes, COUNT(r) AS downvotes

OPTIONAL MATCH (t)<-[r:FLAGGED]-(:person)    
RETURN upvotes, downvotes, COUNT(r) AS flags
```

A couple of miscellaneous items:

Be careful about using Neo IDs as a long-term reference because they can be recycled.

Use [parameters](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/cypher-parameters.html) whenever possible for performance / security (`WHERE ID(t)={topic_id}`)

Also, labels are generally `TitleCase`.  See [The Zen of Cypher](http://nigelsmall.com/zen) guide.

Answer (score 0):

Check this query, i think it will help you.

```html
MATCH (p:person)-[a:UPVOTED]->(t:topic),
(p)-[b:DOWNVOTED]->(t),(p)-[c:FLAGGED]->(t) 
WHERE ID(t)=4 
RETURN COUNT(a) as a_count,COUNT(b) as b_count,COUNT(c) as c_count;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current `MATCH` requires that the **same `person` node** (identified by `p`) have relationships of **all 3 types** with `t`. This is because an identifier is bound to a specific node (or relationship, or value), and (unless hidden by a `WITH` clause, which you do not have in your query) will reference that same node (or relationship, or value) throughout a query.

Based on your expected results, I am assuming that you are just trying to count the number of relationships of those 3 types between *any* `person` and `t`. If so, this is a performant way to do that:

```
MATCH (t:topic)
WHERE ID(t) = 4
MATCH (:person)-[r:UPVOTED|DOWNVOTED|FLAGGED]->(t)
RETURN REDUCE(s=[0,0,0], x IN COLLECT(r) |
  CASE TYPE(x)
    WHEN 'UPVOTED' THEN [s[0]+1, s[1], s[2]]
    WHEN 'DOWNVOTED' THEN [s[0], s[1]+1, s[2]]
    ELSE [s[0], s[1], s[2]+1]
  END
) As res;
```

`res` is an array with the number of `UPVOTED`, `DOWNVOTED`, and `FLAGGED` relationships, respectively, between any `person` and `t`.

Another approach would be to use separate `OPTIONAL MATCH` statements for each relationship type, returning three `COUNT(DISTINCT x)` values. But the above query uses a single `MATCH` statement, greatly reducing the number of DB hits, which are generally expensive.