# Neo4J Multiple Match Statement in Single Query

Tags: node.js, neo4j

I want to get Total Count of VoteUp and VoteDown on Pixel in Single Query but it return **TRUE RESULT** when it have Greater then Zero Value that means **VoteUp** and **VoteDown** Greater then Zero.

```
MATCH (n:pixel)-[vu:vote_up]-(:users), 
  (n:pixel)-[vd:vote_down]-(:users)  
  WHERE ID(n)=7445 RETURN count(vu),count(vd)
```

Above My Query. it return wrong result when **VoteUp** Zero and **VoteDown** Greater then Zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got Solution of My Question from Following Query:

```
MATCH (n:pixel)WHERE ID(n)=7445 
RETURN  
size((n)-[:vote_up]-(:users)) as VoteUp,
size((n)-[:vote_down]-(:users)) as VoteDown
```

Finded Reference From **[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33863719/return-multiple-relationship-counts-for-one-match-statement)**

Comment: If you can remove the `:users` label from your expression it's faster

Comment: @MichaelHunger Thanks for your suggession